# Helper Methods: Passing ClientContext vs using list.Context

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I am creating some helper methods for a SharePoint Online CSOM development project.  Are there any issues with using the Context from the List object or should I explicitly pass the `ClientContext` to the method?

```
public static ListItem (List list, ListItemCreationInformation listItemCreationInfo, string title)
{
   ListItem Item= list.AddItem(listItemCreationInfo);
   item["Title"] = title;
   item.Update();

   list.Context.ExecuteQuery();  // Is this okay?  If so, why not?

   return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use `list.Context.ExecuteQuery()` as `list.Context` is the same object as the one which loads the list, you do not need to pass the context again.

BR